# строю квадратный div с параметрами 100 на 100 пикселей, а на сайте получается прямоугольник

Tags: html, css

[image: сам сайт][1]]

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>индекс</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="images/fdwUO2tJnI4.jpg" alt="">
  <a href="#">ссылка 1</a>
  <a href="#">ссылка 2</a>
  <a href="#">ссылка 3</a>
  <div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Проблема явно не в том коде который приведен здесь. В сниппете все работает корректно.

Comment: проблема в самой среде написания может быть?

Comment: О какой среде речь? Проблема скорее всего во всем остальном коде или в том что Вы не сохранили измененный файл и тп.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо за помощь)

Comment: `div {` у такого селектора едва ли не низший вес из возможных, его могло перебить все что угодно. например `body > *{height: 200px}` или `a + div{height: 150px;}` или точно такой же `div {` но находящийся в коде ниже. именно поэтому желательно *вставлять в вопросы весь код, а не какой то его кусок* и раз уж на странице есть `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">` его содержимое я бы глянул в первую очередь.